# Why in the world does a heap need to make sure it allocates in 8-byte alignments?

Tags: heap, word

4-bytes = word;
8-bytes = 2x word

Then why doesn't the heap just go with 4-byte alignment (because it will be grabbing a word at a time anyway, right?)

If we went with 8-byte alignments, why not 12? 16?

Comment: note: it's defined by the platform. for example: the alignment is 16 on osx.

Comment: It's a good tradeoff I guess. But you do need other alignments for SSE operations, like 64 or 128 bit boundaries. Some platforms do not support unaligned data "Itanium" and even x86/64 has performance penalties when accessing unaligned data.

Comment: @Justin: But don't the 8-byte and 16-byte alignment schemes cause a lot of fragmentation in the heap? Consider allocating 4 integers in the heap: if you did 8-byte alignment then it would take up 32 bytes. 16-byte alignment would take up 64!

Comment: @Dark: you're a little confused about alignment - it's only the *start* of the block that is N-byte aligned. What you do within the block is up to you. Note also that each heap block typically has a small book-keeping overhead associated with it, so alignment padding is just one additional cost per block allocated, and the reason why allocating lots of small blocks may be considered inefficient use of memory.

Comment: It can lead to fragmentation (see also Paul R's explanation). It also reduces the maximum number of allocations a process could utilize (at any given time). To counter this problem, one must often move to 64 bit, use specialized allocators, or reduce the number of heap allocations your programs requires (often using larger, but fewer allocations in exchange). You can also use distributed processing. Fortunately, many programs won't approach these limits. Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit

Comment: So I guess what I am asking is, what could be the rational behind the designers of my Heap to make it 8-byte aligned rather than 4 or 16?

Comment: sizeof(double) == 8 and sizeof(long) == 8 on many architectures, so having a minimum alignment of 8 byte makes sense, especially for 64 bit architectures. Some architectures even have 16 byte alignment (e.g. Mac OS X) so that you automatically get SIMD alignment for AltiVec/SSE etc without needing additional non-standard dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efficiency and CPU architecture. I remember when the Alpha chips came out, they could only read memory on 32 bit boundaries. If you wanted to read byte 3, you'd load a 32-bit number then have to rotate the result to isolate the byte you want. A traditional byte-by-byte string compare was quite inefficient in this architecture.

That being said, I'm not sure what modern processors do. It's been a while since I had to deal with this.

Comment: Hmm.. but these are 32-bit machines. I'm not sure why we need to access in 64-bit patterns for the heap?

Comment: No, the Alpha was a 64 bit CPU. Alignment requirements do not always coincide with register widths, especially when a CPU has registers of varying width.

Comment: MSalters - The Alpha was 64 bit processor but memory reads were aligned on 32 bit boundaries (99% sure). I was working for a company who implemented their own VM and we were considering aligning our strings on 4-byte boundaries to allow faster comparisons. That being said, this was almost 20 years ago and my brain is rapidly failing.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is "It doesn't". The alignment is associated with the implementation details of the heap manager, nothing more. Your heap manager may have an alignment requirement for various reasons, such as efficiency, architecture, whim of the writer or what ever. If you have a reason to care, please share it with us.

BTW:

> 4-bytes = word 8-bytes = 2x word

This is an assumption, is incorrect, and has lead to many varied, sometimes expensive and always inexcusable software porting problems. The size of a word depends on the hardware architecture, OS, language and compiler being used.

Comment: for IA32 a word is 32-bits, pretty straightforward...?

Comment: Maybe, but absolutely irrelevant, unless you are designing a malloc package.

Comment: Doesn't the size of a *word* depend only on the CPU arch?

Comment: A 'word' is normally used to describe the natural size of a block of data on for the specific CPU, however, there is no standard definition for what size it is. If you explicitly require an 8 bit byte, use the term octet, and explicitly define a word as a certain number of octets. Essentially far to many developers stuff things up making grossly incompetent assumptions that 4 bytes = a word etc......it's 2011, we have had 50 years to get this basic Comp Sci stuff right.

Comment: Windows still calls 32 bits a `DWORD` (Double Word), and `WORD` remains 16 bits.